# Select only immediate children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an arbitrarily deep list

```
<ul id="tehList">
<li>
  <ul>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
  <li></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have a jQuery object that references a specific li in this list.  For example var tehList = $("#tehList li");

How can I select only the **immediate** children of tehList?

Thanks!

Travis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#tehList > *
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors

Answer (score 4):

simply do this :

```
$("#tehList li").children();
```

It'll select only the immediate child of tehlist's li